# Despite the high public support to fight Russia, why are some family members of soldiers protesting in Ukraine and making demands?

Tags: ukraine, military, protests

As this answer points out, [political support to fight the Russians](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82106/45056) and retrieve occupied territories remains high among the public in  Ukraine. So I was surprised when I came across the news that [families of soldiers, across Ukraine, are publicly protesting](https://indianexpress.com/photos/world-news/ukraine-mandatory-military-service-cap-18-months/) and apparently asking for a "cap" on military service time.

This has me confused.

The standard practice in modern warfare now is that soldiers are relieved from the battle front periodically, to allow them to rest and recuperate. Without such recuperation soldiers become battle weary and make mistakes that can cost them their life and / or the battle. I also understand that Ukraine has a manpower issue in its military vis the Russians who have a larger army (due to a bigger population than Ukraine). This means every soldier is valuable for Ukraine, and it cannot realistically set any "cap" on military service, as the conflict continues to drag on. But, realistically no soldier can keep fighting for months together at a stretch without any rest and recuperation.

One of the demands of the protestors is an 18-month tenure for drafted soldiers:

> Since the conflict is expected to drag on into next year, the protesters demanded that the cap of 18 months be regularised for the mandatory military service. Currently, the service tenure is open-ended for draftees, and putting the 18-month cap on it would make it same as before the war. Hundreds of wives, mothers, children and relatives of the Ukrainian soldiers formed a loose national network and demanded that the Ukrainian Parliament consider possibly changing the serving time.

I assume that means the protestors are demanding that those who have served 18 months be completely relieved from the Army. But this would significantly weaken the Ukranian military, and demanding such a thing also goes against the popular sentiment that Ukraine needs to fight on.

My questions are:

1. What has prompted these protests in Ukraine now?
2. Do the protestors understand the repercussions of their demands?
3. What has been the government's response to the protestors so far?
4. Has the Ukranian military not been following the standard practise of allowing proper rest and recuperation time for its soldiers? If yes, why?

Comment: You seem to pretty much answer all the Qs in the paras before, so I'm voting to close this. At best what's left to answer is something about the inner motivation for making those demands, which is a little O/T.

Comment: FWTW, [according](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2023-10-27/war-weary-mothers-wives-and-children-of-ukrainian-soldiers-demand-a-cap-on-military-service-time) to LA Times there were about 100 people at that protest. Magnitudes more have fled across the Moldovan border to avoid the draft altogether, judging by the 19,000 that were [caught](https://www.euronews.com/2023/09/01/i-was-afraid-of-it-the-ukrainians-dodging-conscription-and-fleeing-the-country). That happens in any war.

Comment: @Fizz Does my opinion in the question actually answer all 4 questions factually?

Comment: As part of the review process, I edited the title to reflect that it is *some* family members (instead of implying *all* or *most* family members).  I also removed the word *"unrealistic"* because that appears to be the OP's opinion (and could be part of someone's answer, but not the question itself).  If you disagree with either of my edits, feel free to modify them.  I also voted for the question to be closed because it asks too many questions.  If closed, I think it can easily be reopened if the focus is narrowed to ask a single question.

Comment: There's an element of contradiction in the question, between saying R&R is good for performance, and saying more R&R would be bad for performance.

Comment: I am not sure what the point of this Q is.  Yes, at a macro, country, level, 18month tours of duty is unrealistic, for Ukraine as a whole.  Russia has 3x the population so maintaining manpower parity on the front line requires mobilization of a high order.  On a micro, personal, level, why would one expect individuals not to object to being put in harm's way for an indefinite period of time?  This is a "does a bear poo in the woods?" type of question.  That said, existential wars, like WW2, mostly did not see anyone get released for the duration.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That's the crust of my question - does 18 months mean that Ukraine is making their soldiers fight for 18 months without any rest or recuperation (which would be incredibly stupid)? And why are protestors demanding soldiers be discharged after 18 months, rather than adequate rest and recuperation for them so that they can recharge and fight for their country efficiently? (As has been pointed out, public support continues to be high for the war).

Comment: I see I had voted to close this but then answered anyway as the issue had been addressed by officials before this [small] protest. I've voted to reopen, in case there's more to be said.

Comment: I dunno about "attempt to promote or discredit", but this definitely feels too broad to me. It needs to be narrowed down so it's only asking one question, not four.

Comment: @F1Krazy All the 4 questions are related to the same topic, in my opinion. But please feel free to edit the question if you think different. I honestly have lost my enthusiasm for this SE due to the blatant pro-US bias by some of the mods and members to make this SE into another low quality [echo chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_(media)) on the internet rather than a decent platform with internationally diverse ideas on politics being discussed academically, as SEs are meant to be.

Comment: I voted to reopen, it seems neutral enough to me. As for asking multiple questions: my recommendation for related stuff is to decide what is the most important question, make that question stand out and in the title and make the other questions kind of "bonus" by combining them and marking as optional. Or do separate questions. This is a good internationally approved academic practice of separation of issues.

Answer (score 3):

The [size](https://www.nationalworld.com/news/world/russia-ukraine-war-ukraine-army-size-compared-russia-uk-us-nato-3581362) of Ukrainian army is 200 000 or about. This is less than the combat capable population of the country. Hence it is possible to suggest that more men should share the burden of fighting by introducing more rotation while not opposing the same continuation of the resistance. It is more about how.

There are no very "standard practices" of rotation during war time. At least during WWII, I think no one on either side was released from the war till it was over.

Comment: As the article points out, they had 900,000 reservists, and after the draft and training, the size had increased to 500,000+ ... but your answer doesn't answer any of my questions. (And, if I remember right, this practice of rotating soldiers was introduced in modern armies after WW2).

Comment: @sfxedit: I think you're confusing two issues: lack of rotation *from the front line* with service *ending altogether* after set period. The protesters in your Q ask for the latter, not for the former. If UK+Ukraine are to be believed, Russia is not doing much rotations either https://kyivindependent.com/uk-defense-ministry-lack-of-rotations-likely-one-of-key-factors-lowering-russian-armys-morale/ People didn't get let off the army after 18 months in WW2.

Comment: @Fizz The reason I mentioned it is if the former was being done properly, the latter wouldn't be required. Often times, rest and recovery includes emotional recovery too, and soldiers are allowed to go back to their family temporarily. (But if you think my opinions are creating confusions, I can remove it from the questions).

Comment: During WW2 general practice was to keep people enlisted for the duration.  But not in all cases, for all armies.  WW2 strategic B17/B24 bombing raids over Germany had you going home after 25 missions (few survived that long).  In Vietnam, US draftees got rotated out after a year.  Which was militarily problematic as they got taken out as soon as they got more veteran/better at killing and staying alive.  A number of armies would also desk-promote you away from harm's way after a while:  the Luftwaffe was unusual to keep its aces flying until they died.

Comment: @sfxedit So the US Vietnam practice, while historical, is hardly considered best practice, in terms of efficiency.  Not even in terms of casualties:  newbies die at highly amplified rates on battlefield, so cycling less people for longer would have resulted in less deaths overall.  And overall, it is hard to make many claims about "modern armies":  most Western militaries have moved to professional, not drafted, militaries since WW2.  And no Western nation has faced a comparable threat level since WW2.  So post-WW2 Western history does not lend itself to easy comparisons w Ukraine.

Answer (score 3):

I'll [ignore](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/can-we-declare-motivations-off-topic) the internal motivation question(s) and address [briefly]

> What has been the government's response to the protestors so far?

Probably nothing, given that only 100 people showed up at that protest in Kyiv, [according](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2023-10-27/war-weary-mothers-wives-and-children-of-ukrainian-soldiers-demand-a-cap-on-military-service-time) to LA Times. (Protest which only happened 2 days ago. The newspaper also says that "scores" of people showed up in 6 other cites.)

As for lack/sparsity of rotations from the front line, let alone letting soldiers end their service altogether after a set period, I found [this](https://hromadske.ua/en/posts/everyone-has-to-fight-it-is-only-fair-soldiers-waiting-for-rotation) from February.

> We asked the General Staff what the rotation procedure is and whether all those who have been fighting for a long time will be replaced. We were told that they do not comment on these topics.

Anyhow, the Ukrainian media (citing some UK gov't source) [says](https://kyivindependent.com/uk-defense-ministry-lack-of-rotations-likely-one-of-key-factors-lowering-russian-armys-morale/) that Russian troops aren't getting much rotations either, so that's probably part of the implicit semi-official response.

Also, it looks like Zelenskyy himself addressed that demobilization [after set period] Q before:

> Citizens have registered several electronic petitions on the president's website, asking [...] to allow the military, who have been at war for a year, to demobilize. However, a similar petition had already gained 25,000 votes, and both Defense Minister Reznikov and President Zelenskyy responded that in wartime, military personnel can be demobilized only in accordance with Article 26 of the Law of Ukraine “On Military Duty and Military Service” — upon reaching the age of 60, for health reasons, due to a court conviction, etc.

FWTW, for perspective, around 19,000 Ukrainians tried to flee across the borders to avoid the draft but were [caught](https://www.euronews.com/2023/09/01/i-was-afraid-of-it-the-ukrainians-dodging-conscription-and-fleeing-the-country). (And surely some uncounted number succeeded.)

[According](https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2023/08/31/on-the-train-from-kyiv-to-the-front-ukrainian-soldiers-anger-boils_6117642_4.html) to Le Monde,

> Ukrainian soldiers are rarely granted leave due to a lack of replacements.

That piece says that rather than being demobilized (as those protesters asked) some soldiers were given a 10 day leave after 1.5 years. And that was instead of the 30 days allowed in peace time.

---

There's a bit more info on the troubles that Ukraine has with keeping the ranks filled, [published](https://time.com/6329188/ukraine-volodymyr-zelensky-interview/) more recently in *Time*

> according to U.S. and European estimates, the toll has long surpassed 100,000 on each side of the war. It has eroded the ranks of Ukraine’s armed forces so badly that draft offices have been forced to call up ever older personnel, raising the average age of a soldier in Ukraine to around 43 years. “They’re grown men now, and they aren’t that healthy to begin with,” says the close aide to Zelensky. “This is Ukraine. Not Scandinavia.”
>
> The picture looked different at the outset of the invasion. One branch of the military, known as the Territorial Defense Forces, reported accepting 100,000 new recruits in the first 10 days of all-out war. The mass mobilization was fueled in part by the optimistic predictions of some senior officials that the war would be won in months if not weeks. “Many people thought they could sign up for a quick tour and take part in a heroic victory,” says the second member of the President’s team.
>
> **Now recruitment is way down**. As conscription efforts have intensified around the country, stories are spreading on social media of draft officers pulling men off trains and buses and sending them to the front. Those with means sometimes bribe their way out of service, often by paying for a medical exemption. Such episodes of corruption within the recruitment system became so widespread by the end of the summer that on Aug. 11 Zelensky fired the heads of the draft offices in every region of the country.
>
> The decision was intended to signal his commitment to fighting graft. But the move backfired, according to the senior military officer, as recruitment nearly ground to a halt without leadership. The fired officials also proved difficult to replace, in part because the reputation of the draft offices had been tainted. “Who wants that job?” the officer asks. “It’s like putting a sign on your back that says: corrupt.”

This is no doubt related to the long service periods for those already drafted, probably in more than one way. E.g. some probably have qualms about volunteering now given the apparently indefinite period that they might need to serve. And vice-versa, the lack of sufficient new volunteers means that those already serving need to do long tours with little leave. It's a catch-22 in some ways.

---

FWTW, Russia also appears to be lengthening the tours of duty. At least those [of prisoners](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-68140873). No more getting pardoned after 6 months. Now they have to serve till the end of the war.

---

WaPo [reported](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2024/02/08/ukraine-soldiers-shortage-infantry-russia/) on Feb 8 that the personnel situation was pretty dire for the Ukrainians:

> Oleksandr, a battalion commander, said the companies in his unit on average are staffed at about 35 percent of what they should be. A second battalion commander from an assault brigade said that is typical for units that carry out combat tasks. [...]
>
> Especially in winter, when the weather conditions are hard, infantry should be rotated out after about three days. But because units lack troops, deployments get extended — or personnel intended for the rear get pressed into front-line duty despite being ill-prepared for it.
>
> Serhiy, 41, a platoon commander fighting in Avdiivka, the site of Russia’s most intense assaults, said he and his men are rarely rotated out after just three days. More often five days go by — or even 10.
>
> Dmytro, another deputy battalion commander in a different brigade, said his infantry typically get two days of rest after five to 10 days holding the line, and because most of his soldiers are over the age of 40, their lack of physical fitness compounds the problems. [...]
>
> The lack of rotations is a problem across the Ukrainian military — not just for infantry on the line. Soldiers might get a few days off to go home and see their families, but rarely more. They say they are still motivated to fight the Russian invaders, but also that they need rest and more men beside them.